# How to extract from list items that are 2digits"."2digits only in Iron Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, filtering

I have list of strings and need to find all that follow this logic

```
twodigits.twodigits  
Example| Correct?  
----------- | ------  
03.38 | Yes  
10.59  | Yes  
10.23 m3/h | No  
50.8 mm | No
```

I tried only to look for "." but did not work...

```
for i in elements:
    id = i.Id
    if i.Text[2:3] == '.':
        i.Text= ''
        atext1.append(i.Text)
```

I found this but not sure how to use it in my code?

```
str_extract_all(text, "\\d{2}.\\d{2}") %>%
```

My current code from answers:

```
for i in elements:
    id = i.Id
    match = search('\d{2}\.\d{2}$',i.strip())
    if match: 
        atext1.append(match.string)
        i.Text= ''
        #atext1.append(i.Text)
    else:
        atext2.append(i.Text)
    atext.append(i.Text)
```

another try but still does not work

```
for i in elements:
    id = i.Id
    k = i.Text
    atext3.append(k)

    match=search('\d{2}\.\d{2}$',k.strip())
    if match: atext4.append(match.string)
        i.Text= ''
```

this one aslo no success

```
for i in elements:
    id = i.Id
    k = i.Text
    atext3.append(k)
    if k.split('.')[0:2].isdigit():
        i.Text= ''
        atext3.append(i.Text)
```

I got this working finally. Thanks all for help

```
import clr
clr.AddReference('ProtoGeometry')
from Autodesk.DesignScript.Geometry import *
clr.AddReference("RevitNodes")
import Revit
clr.ImportExtensions(Revit.Elements)
clr.AddReference("RevitServices")
import RevitServices
from RevitServices.Persistence import DocumentManager
from RevitServices.Transactions import TransactionManager
from System.Collections.Generic import *
clr.AddReference("RevitAPI")
import Autodesk
from Autodesk.Revit.DB import *
from re import search

doc = DocumentManager.Instance.CurrentDBDocument
uiapp = DocumentManager.Instance.CurrentUIApplication
app = uiapp.Application


#The inputs to this node will be stored as a list in the IN variable.

#from re import search

atext3 = []
atextTrue = []
atextFalse = []
atextAll = []

#unwrap all elements to use with API
elements = []
for i in IN[0]:
    elements.append(UnwrapElement(i))

TransactionManager.Instance.EnsureInTransaction(doc)

for i in elements:
    atext3 = i.Text
    match = search('\d{2}\.\d{2}$', atext3.strip())
    if match:
        i.Text = 'deletedTEXT'      
        atextTrue.append(i.Text)
    else:
        atextFalse.append(i.Text)

    atextAll.append(i)

TransactionManager.Instance.TransactionTaskDone()

#Assign your output to the OUT variable
OUT =  atextTrue, atextFalse, atextAll
```

Comment: Yes of course list is at the top here is example [03.38, 10.59, 10.23 m3/h, 50.8 mm, koza, VCD, 48l/s, 10.203, 02.72, 03.55.  ]

Comment: in the case of `10.23 m3/h` would you want to extract `10.23` or skip it entirely because it doesn't contain only `twodigits.twodigits`?

Comment: I want to skip it... aslo I need to inster this into my if as I need to replace this text for each item in list and if is matching then replace with None so i.Text= '' this line follows

Comment: given the example you posted above, can you post a sample of your expected output?

Comment: Thanks all, for those amazing options...this looks a bit complex for me and not sure how to implement into my code. I use Dynamo and connect to Revit. So I have 10000 elements reading text and have list. Need to find for each index if is match my pattern then run line to replace this index value with Nothing ( i.Text= '' ). As in my code above...let me try all those options

Comment: What do you expect `atext`,`atext1` and, `atext2` to look like when your done? Please post a sample.

Comment: aText is only visual output. All I really need is to run check if match then run i.Text=''. I am working on elements that contains lots of data.

Comment: Gave my answer a try?

Answer (score 0):

```
def fits_pattern(s):
    s = s.strip()
    return len(s) == 5 and s[2] == '.' and (s[:2] + s[-2:]).isdigit()


for test_string in ['03.38', '10.59 ', '10.23 m3/h', '50.8 mm',
                    'ab.cd', '12.3d', '1234', '12345', '', '     12.34     ']:
    print(repr(test_string))
    print(fits_pattern(test_string))
```

Output:

```
'03.38'
True
'10.59 '
True
'10.23 m3/h'
False
'50.8 mm'
False
'ab.cd'
False
'12.3d'
False
'1234'
False
'12345'
False
''
False
'     12.34     '
True
```

A regex solution would be:

```
import re

def fits_pattern(s):
    return re.match(r'\s*\d\d\.\d\d\s*', s)
```

`\s*`: 0 or more spaces (including newlines, tabs, etc.)
`\d`: a digit
`\.`: a literal `.`, since `.` by itself is something different.
`r'...'`: a raw string literal, useful for regexes to avoid having loads of `\` characters in your string literal.

Answer (score 0):

```
from re import search

l=['03.38', '10.59 ', '10.23 m3/h', '50.8 mm']
atext1=[]
for i in l:
    match=search('\d{2}\.\d{2}$',i.strip())
    if match: atext1.append(match.string)



print(atext1) #['03.38', '10.59']
```

The `\d{2}\.\d{2}$` will match any element in `l` that **ends** with two digits, a period and two more digits. The `i.strip()` removes leading and trailing blanks -- that way `'10.59 '` will become `'10.59'` and match this regular expression.

Comment: do you have the `re` package installed? you can check by entering `help('modules')` at your Python command line and see if it's in the list.

Comment: What about modification ie. Ca.16 this will be \C\a\.\d{2}$ ? what do  we use $ for?

Comment: @michal The `$` essentially means "ends with". Saying 'abc$' means you're trying to match a string that ends with "abc". This would match "123abc" but not "123abc1".

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in elements:
    if not len(list(i.Text)) > 5:
        if len(i.split('.')) > 0:
           if i.split('.')[0:2].isdigit():
               if i.split('.')[3:].isdigit():
                   print("Yes")
```

Comment: In line 4 I have SyntaxError: expected an indented block

Comment: Do I need any library?  _Warning: IronPythonEvaluator.EvaluateIronPythonScript operation failed. 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 47, in <module>
AttributeError: 'TextNote' object has no attribute 'split'_

Comment: @Michal, there is a syntax error. Should be a `:` at the end of line 4

Comment: @LMc you mean line 3 _if len(i.split('.')) > 0:_

Comment: this code looks clear but  _if k.split('.')[0:2].isdigit():_ this line does not work for me

Answer (score 0):

```
# being that you provided no details on how this info is stored, other than "a list of strings", I'm assuming it's stored like so:
lst_info = ['11.11','1.11','22.11','22.22']

def is_number(s):
    try:
        float(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False


def function(p):
    new_lst = []
    piece = []
    for e in p:
        if len(e) > 4:
            if (is_number(e[0:2]), is_number(e[3:]), e[2] == '.'):
                piece.append([str(e)])
                piece.append([': Yes'])
                new_lst.append(piece)
                piece = []
        else:
            piece.append([str(e)])
            piece.append([': No'])
            new_lst.append(piece)
            piece = []
    result = ''
    for e in new_lst:
        result += (' ' * (9 - len(str(e[0])))) + (str(e[0]) + ' | ' + str(e[1]) + '\n')
    return result

print function(lst_info)
# prints
['11.11'] | [': Yes']
 ['1.11'] | [': No']
['22.11'] | [': Yes']
['22.22'] | [': Yes']
```